# EF DbContext and StructureMap scoping

Tags: entity-framework-4, structuremap

Ok, I give up...

What I want is to share the EF4's DbContext instance per request. I configured StructureMap like this:

```
For<MyContext>().Use(new MyContext("LocalhostConnString"));
```

But when I refresh my site, or even open it in another browser, I get the **same exact instance** of MyContext. Why is this shared across requests?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes... about 4 characters. Try:

```
For<MyContext>().Use(() => new MyContext("LocalhostConnString"));
```

If you give StructureMap an object instance, it will treat that instance as a singleton and return the same one every time. If instead you give it a lambda that creates an instance, it will run that lambda each time the type is requested.

Comment: So, "each time the type is requested", but not once per request?

Comment: @Roman Royter Exactly my question. How should I do it per request?

Comment: the default lifecycle is Transient and that means a nested container for MVC / Web API which effectively means per request - apparently